# Two different versions of events - what is true?

Tags: probability

Christopher, John and Thomas had a test. Lecturer supposes that Christopher cheated Lecturer assumes that probability that Christopher cheated is $0,8$ so he decided talk to John and Thomas.  John is friend of Christopher and tell
false if Christophger cheated with probablity $0,2$, but he tell true when Christopher didn't cheated with probablity $1$.
However Thomas tell true with probablity 1 when Christopher cheated, but when he didn't cheated Thomas tell true with probablity $0,7$
What is the probability that Christopher cheaded when we assume that Thomas and John something different.

Look at my point of view, and try to understand me where I am wrong, please.

$JS$ - Thomas tell false 
$JP$ - John tell true.
$TP$ - Thomas tell true
$TS$ - Thomas tell false
$KS$ - Christopher cheated
$KN$ - Christopher didn't cheated.

So,
$$Pr(TS) = Pr(TS|KS) \cdot Pr(KS) + Pr(TS|KN) * Pr(KN) = 0 + 0,3 Pr (KN) $$
$$Pr (TP) = Pr(TP|KS)Pr(KS)+Pr(TP|KN)Pr(KN) = Pr(KS)+0,7Pr(KN) $$
Analogously,
 $Pr(JS) = 0,2Pr(KS)$
$Pr(JP) = 0,8Pr(KS)+Pr(KN)$
And now
$Pr(KS)+Pr(KN) = 1$
$Pr(JP) + Pr(TS) = 1$
$Pr(JS) + Pr(TP) = 1$
When I tried solve it now I will get irrational numbers.
Where am I wrong - it is crucial question for me.

Comment: You have a system of linear equations with rational coefficients.  The solution, if unique, must be in rational numbers. Apparently you made a mistake in solving it.

Comment: pay your attention that solution may be negative number or number greater than $1$. So try to help me again please

Comment: Ok, I had a real solution. I'll show it after.

Answer (score 0):

So I show my solution. fasten your seatbelt :)

$KS$- Christopher cheated
$KN$ - Christopher don't cheated
$SI$ - Thomas and John tell different version of event.
$JTS$ - John claims that Ch. cheated
$JTN $ John claims that Ch. didn't cheated
$TTN $ Thomas claims that Ch. didn't cheated
$TTS $ Thomas claims that Ch chetead

$$Pr(KS|SI) = \frac{Pr(SI|KS)Pr(KS)}{Pr(SI|KS)Pr(KS) + Pr(SI|KN)Pr(KN)} $$
$$Pr(SI|KS) = \frac{Pr(SI\cap KS)}{Pr(KS)} $$
$$Pr(SI\cap KS) = Pr(JTS \cap TTN \cap KS)+ Pr(JTN\cap TTS \cap KS) $$
$$ Pr(JTS \cap TTN \cap KS) = 0$$
$$Pr(JTN\cap TTS \cap KS) = Pr(JTN \cap KS) Pr(TTS|JTN\cap KS) = 0,2Pr(KS) $$
$$Pr(Pr(JTN\cap KS) = Pr(JTN|KS)Pr(KS) = 0,2Pr(KS) $$
$$Pr(TTS|JTN\cap KS) = 1$$
$$Pr(SI\cap KS) = 0 + 0,2Pr(KS) $$
$$Pr(SI|KS) = \frac{0,2Pr(KS)}{Pr(KS)} = 0,2 $$
And analgously I computed:
$$Pr(SI|KN) = \frac{0,3Pr(KN)}{Pr(KN)} = 0,3 $$
Finally:
$$Pr(KS|SI) = \frac{0,2 * 0,8}{0,2*0,8 + 03*0,8} = \frac{2}{5} $$

Ok ?